# Three.js bloomPass make the whole scene into 8 bit look alike

Tags: javascript, three.js

Does any one have any idea why is it like this ? i followed the tutorial on youtube and also tried to use the examples from three.js website.

So this is how my scene looks like with EffectComposer

```
    const composer = new EffectComposer(renderer);
    composer.addPass(new RenderPass(scene, camera));
```

[image]

This is how it looks like after i added a unrealbloomPass to it

```
   const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    bloomPass.threshold = 0.1;
    bloomPass.strength = 3.0;
    bloomPass.radius = 1.0;
    composer.addPass(bloomPass);
```

[image]

```
    composer.addPass(new GlitchPass());
```

This is how it looks like after i added a GlitchPass to it.
[image]

After all my main goal here is just to make the "enemy ships" gltf objects glow in this scene. or do i have to create a new scene for the enemy ships and let them glow in that scene and render both scene later ?